# How to to disable normalization in Cloud Speech-to-Text

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I am using Google Cloud speech-to-text API to transcribe audio files. And when I try to recognise "I have five hundred dollars" I have a response with Inverse Text Normalization (ITN) like "I have $500".
I would like to turn off ITN and have a response like "I have five hundred dollars", but I can't find how to turn it off. I know how to do it in Microsoft ASR, but is this feature available in Google?

I have tried to use:
enable_word_time_offsets=True,
enable_word_confidence=True,
But it still gives me ITN response

Comment: I think Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API does not provide a direct option to disable ITN.